# Why I get Forbidden when trying to install drush on Travis CI via composer?

Tags: composer-php, travis-ci, drush

This composer command fails on my Travis CI project ([example failed build](https://travis-ci.org/klausi/rules/jobs/23671085)):

```
composer global require drush/drush:dev-master
```

It fails with:

```
The 'https://api.github.com/repos/RobLoach/Console_Table/zipball/9f80c91a9fc01a3cce71ae80ea5bd473cb0eba4c'
URL could not be accessed: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

although that file can be downloaded just fine.

The `.travis.yml` file is [here](https://github.com/klausi/rules/blob/8.x-3.x/.travis.yml)

Comment: Looks like you have it working on your latest build. Anything else you need help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added

```
composer selfupdate
```

to the .travis.yml file and now that build step passes. Not sure if that really fixed the problem or if this will happen again as random fail.

Comment: Looking at the failure, I think it's just a random connection fail error. Something that can happen sometimes :)